# How to displays only selected fields from the report at runtime in c# winforms using crystal report?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I am developing an win forms application for now i want to generate a crystal
  report that is dynamically. Means if my table contains 30 fields so i will 
  design my 30 fields on front end just take checkbox or dropdown so, based up
  on the user selection i want to generate report i.e,dynamically. So i have
  already but i got a bunch of errors just like as asking prompt message for
  enter a value.(If i have set list of values option as "Dynamic" too)

Those issues are not solvable me i irritated a lot.

Can you give me any reference or procedure to make report as dynamic in my
  win forms using c# and database as SQL.

Thanks help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In case of dynamic Report with dynamic fields, I afraid you have to create the report programmatically. So you can iterate over all existing objects in your report in ReportDocument and either take them out or add them to the report depending on the date you want to visualize.